# How would we create a device to detect communication using the x-ray and gamma bandwidth? Like a radio. But x-ray gamma spectrum

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, cosmic-microwave-background, x-rays, radio-frequency, gamma-rays

I realize the dipole would have to be small enough (in the nucleus of an atom range) and we don't have any mechanism that is small enough to demodulate the frequencies at this rate. But is there some other way to build a machine that would use this form of communication?

I have heard information that if ET are communicating they are using this bandwidth, not by generating the energy needed as we do with radio communication but using the abundant cosmic radiation (static frequencies). I read the chain from the article "Can gamma rays be generated by alternating current in very high frequency?" and at the end a user said

> Pretty much possible, but not in the direct sense of a simple electronic oscilator.
>
> See Synchrotron light sources

(The article discusses "x-rays" based on the emission origin and application, but synchrotron sources are practical up to MeV range, or not-so-soft gamma rays).

and..

Actually, gamma radiation can be generated in an electric circuit if the voltage is high enough, for example, on the order of $1 \text{MV}$. Experimental evidence of gamma radiation in a long spark is reported in [https://homepages.cwi.nl/~ebert/2015-JPD-Pavlo.pdf](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Eebert/2015-JPD-Pavlo.pdf). They report photon energies above $200 \text{keV}$. I believe this is technically gamma radiation, although the mechanism of generation of gamma radiation in the spark is rather complicated.

So it is possible and if it is possible I'm trying to figure out how to make it. Could someone could point me in the right direction of people to ask, as I am not a particle physicist but an avid reader and metaphysicist?  It would have very amazing consequences if we could detect a signal not generated from earth -- it would shift the entire mindset and structure of our current understanding of reality.

Comment: Detection is a different issue than generating the signal in the first place. Which do you mean - the title and the body are somewhat contradictory.

Comment: X-rays and gamma rays are usually detected with ionization detectors. These devices are, essentially, just a volume of matter with an electric field in it that separates the ions and the electrons. While there are a few non-trivial concerns in practice, the working principles of these detectors are very simple and can be realized even at home with more or less trivial effort. Will any of these make for a practically useful communications device? No.

Comment: Thank you for you responses, I’m sry for sounding like a novice bcuz I am, might be a good thing. I’ll make it simple, I heard we could upgrade our equipment on earth easily to pick up the signals broadcast is the cosmic radiation X-ray/ gamma freqs). They then need to be demodulated and the signals would sound like musical chords (similar to FSK, frequency shift keying). The signals are not in code. But it wouldn’t matter if we could understand it, just that it exists. It would need to reach 10 ly from earth. I want to build it. I knw some engineers on COSI but want to ask you 1st. Thx again.

Comment: where have you heard this?